# Elequent Relationships Error

Tags: laravel-5, frameworks

I have created a posts table & comments table for posts comments.
I want to get my posts with their comments ...

In my Post Model :

```
public function comments()
{
     return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```

In my Comment Model :

```
public function post()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}
```

And this is my Controller :

```
public function show($ID)
{
    try {
        $post = Post::findOrFail($ID);
        $comments = Post::find($ID)->comments;
        $randomPosts = Post::all()->random(3);
        return view('show', compact('post','comments','randomPosts'));
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        $posts = Post::orderBy('ID', 'DESC')->paginate(5);
        return view('welcome', compact('posts'));            
    }
}
```

But I get this error :
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$ID

What is my problem ?

Comment: you need to assign the $ID variable to your id that you want to retrieve the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the $ID variable to your id that you want to retrieve the post

For example let's say that you want the post with id 1 and its comment.

First you can retrieve the comments for first article like this:

```
$comments = App\Post::find(1)->comments;

foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    echo $comment
}
```

Of course you can retrieve the post represents one comment.

For example the post that has the first comment:

```
$comment = App\Comment::find(1);

echo $comment->post->title;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response !

Comment: It's my pleasure. If you want you can read more about here=> https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many